# How do I access SSRS reports with a new user account when the old windows account has been corrupted

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I run SQL Server 2014 locally. My old windows account has been corrupted. I created a new windows account, gave myself sysadmin permissions on SSMS and I can log onto the database fine. I also logged on Reporting Services Configuration Manager and changed the Service Account to the new user account. However I can not access localhost/reportserver on internet explorer.  It's saying I don't have sufficient permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I just found the answer. It's a Trusted Site issue:

To Configure Local Report Server and Report Manager Administration
Complete the configuration steps in this section if you are browsing to a local report server and you see errors similar to the following:

User 'Domain[user name]' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

Trusted Site Settings in the Browser:

Open a browser window with Run as administrator permissions. From the Start menu, click All Programs, right-click Internet Explorer, and select Run as administrator.

Click Allow to continue.

In the URL address, enter the Report Manager URL. For instructions, see Report Manager (SSRS Native Mode) in SQL Server Books Online.

Click Tools.

Click Internet Options.

Click Security.

Click Trusted Sites.

Click Sites.

Add https://[your-server-name]

Clear the check box Require server certification (https:) for all sites in this zone if you are not using HTTPS for the default site.

Click Add.

Click OK.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-a-native-mode-report-server-for-local-administration-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017